# Six degrees of web separation

Tags: popularity-contest

Six degrees of separation is the theory that everyone and everything is six or fewer steps away, by way of introduction, from any other person in the world.

Your challenge here is to write a program which crawls to find out what is exactly 6 links away but connected back to the starting URL through a series of links.

For example if your program is given a starting url of http://vimeo.com it would then potentially (this is a made up example) crawl to:

1. http://www.abc.com links to ->
2. http://www.widgets.com links to ->
3. http://www.gadgets.net links to ->
4. http://www.techcrunch.com links to ->
5. https://twitter.com/techcrunch links to ->
6. http://www.youtube.com/user/techcrunch (finish as we are now 6 links away from the starting URL.)

Rules:

- You can choose your own starting URL.
- Any programming language can be used.
- You most obey sites robots.txt files and not crawl any areas sites disallow.
- Each step must be a new URL from the one you are currently on.
- URLS should only be visited once per crawl.
- You must output the starting URL and each link followed in sequence.

Winner:

- This is a popularity contest so the solution with the most up-votes wins.

Comment: If anyone thinks this would be better as some other type of competition other than code golf, please comment.

Comment: Determining whether two sites are on the same domain or not is *hard*. Browsers have long lists of special cases to deal with it. In order to make this a fair contest, I think you should provide a spec for whether two FQDNs should be considered to be from the same domain or not for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @BenPaton You may want to use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/881/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-vii), especially if you are unsure about your puzzle.

Comment: Does `example.co.uk` count as the same domain as `example2.co.uk`. If not, can you specify why?

Comment: Hello I would say example and example2 count as two distinct domains in this as the strings are different in the names.

Comment: Jan's question is just a specific case of my point. I'm voting to put this question on hold for the time being so that people don't waste time writing answers which might be invalidated when the spec is clarified.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have added a distinct domains rules clarification section. Does this cover everything?

Comment: No. You say that subdomains don't count as new domains, but you don't say why `example.co.uk` and `example2.co.uk` aren't considered as subdomains of `co.uk`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I though that would be obvious? Otherwise I would have asked for 6 distinct top level domains away from the starting URL which would be really hard to find examples of.

Comment: @BenPaton, some TLDs allow registration of `yourdomain.tld` (these include the `com`, `org`, `net`, and some CCTLDs; I suspect that `mil` and `gov` are also in this category, but that might be debatable); others have their own second level domains and allow registration of third level domains (e.g. the `uk` CCTLD). And IIRC it's not even that simple. See also http://publicsuffix.org/list/

Comment: "most up-votes wins" is [tag:popularity-contest].

Comment: what about google.com.br vs bing.com.br vs registro.br?

Comment: google.com.br vs bing.com.br vs registro.br - these are all distinct. google.com.br -> google.com wouldn't count though

Comment: @BenPaton This is a nice idea but really needs to be ironed out a bit more. There seems to be a lot of ambiguity about the rule for distinct domains, and even [parsing a robots.txt file](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=18050&zep=Searcharoo%2fIndexer%2fRobotsTxt.cs&rzp=%2fKB%2fIP%2fSearcharoo_4%2f%2fsearcharoo4.zip) is non-trivial.

Comment: I am surprised there has been so many questions around what constitutes a different domain. To me it seems quite simple. If I'm on bing.com a link to cnn.com is clearly a move a different domain where as another part of bing wouldn't be. Perhaps all the extra rules to clarify this only serve to confuse?

Comment: Your "rules to clarify" completely miss the point. Anyone who would attempt this question understands the difference between a domain and the path component of a URL. The part which needs clarification is how to deal with the real world messiness of the part which ICANN administrates: that is, the desired "are these subdomains of the same domain?" equivalence relationship on FQDNs.

Comment: You're thinking at the wrong level of abstraction: you say that "If I'm on bing.com ... another part of bing wouldn't be [a different domain]": but you need to think in terms of FQDNs at the level of characters, which is all a computer sees, not at the level of "As a human, I know whether or not this FQDN is part of Bing", and you need to consider the world of CCTLDs with registries whose policies have changed over time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor can you provide an example URL where if your code parsed it you wouldn't know whether to classify it as sufficiently different to one you had already examined?

Comment: foo.hanoi.vn vs bar.hanoi.vn: it's not clear from http://www.vnnic.vn/en/domain/cctld-vn?lang=en whether hanoi.vn falls under case m, although appearing in the banner image is suggestive . foo.blogspot.com.ss vs bar.blogspot.com.ss vs quux.com.ss. (Do you know South Sudan's registration policy?) How about the new Chinese language gTLD?

Comment: With foo.hanoi.vn vs bar.hanoi.vn, these would be distinct as this is similar to foo/bar.co.uk. foo.blogspot.com.ss vs bar.blogspot.com.ss would not be distinct as they are both blogspot. Chinese language domains I don't see would work any differently to .com It just needs to be distinct.中文网

Comment: Ben, with your definition of a "domain" this challenge is impossible. You say that `google.com` and `google.com.br` are to be considered the same domain. That subdomains to `twitter.com` are not considered new domains, but subdomains to `hanoi.vn` are. Not only are you having wildly varying depth levels of a "subdomain" but you also consider domains on *different TLDs* to be the same. Did you even know that there is no standardised technical definition of a "subdomain"? ALL domain names are considered subdomains to `.` as far as the DNS specification goes.

Comment: Ok I have simplified the question to try and get away from what constitutes a distinct domain. Can this be taken off hold now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Java, 8623 bytes

It isn't perfect. It has some issues connecting to some URLs and fails to parse the robots.txt properly. However, it's a start.

```
package info.varden.codegolf.sixdegreeslink;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static HashMap<String, String> entities = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> robotstxts = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String init = "";
        for (String s : args) {
            init += s + "%20";
        }
        init = init.substring(0, init.length() - 3);
        try {
            System.out.println("Resolving entites (step 1 of 3)...");
            entities.putAll(getEntitiesFromEnt("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/HTMLlat1.ent"));
            System.out.println("Resolving entites (step 2 of 3)...");
            entities.putAll(getEntitiesFromEnt("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/HTMLsymbol.ent"));
            System.out.println("Resolving entites (step 3 of 3)...");
            entities.putAll(getEntitiesFromEnt("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/HTMLspecial.ent"));
            System.out.println(entities.size() + " entites resolved.\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Starting search from: " + init + "\n");
        IterationInfo initInfo = new IterationInfo();
        IterationInfo info = initInfo;
        try {
            initInfo.scanLink = init;
            initInfo.links.add(init);
            initInfo.domains.add(getDomain(init));
            info = getSixStepsRecursive(initInfo);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long diffTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        long second = (diffTime / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (diffTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        diffTime = diffTime % 1000;

        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", hour, minute, second, diffTime);
        System.out.println("\nCompleted in " + time);
        System.out.println("\nRESULTS:");
        if (info.success) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.links.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(info.links.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't find six degrees step separation!");
        }
    }

    private static IterationInfo getSixStepsRecursive(IterationInfo info) {
        IterationInfo returnInfo = info;
        String[] urls = new String[0];
        try {
            String content = downloadString(info.scanLink);
            content = content.replace("\t", " ").replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ");
            while (content.contains("  ")) content = content.replace("  ", " ");
            urls = content.split("\\Q<a href=\"\\E");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < urls.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (info.iteration == 6) {
                    returnInfo.success = true;
                    return returnInfo;
                }
                returnInfo = info;
                urls[i] = stripHTMLEntities(urls[i].split("\"")[0]);
                if (urls[i].startsWith("//"))
                    urls[i] = "http:" + urls[i];
                if (!urls[i].startsWith("http://") && !urls[i].startsWith("https://")) {
                    System.out.println("Iter " + info.iteration + " - URL failed: Relative or non-HTTP link (" + urls[i] + ")");
                    continue;
                }
                if (!canGetRobotsTxt(urls[i])) {
                    System.out.println("Iter " + info.iteration + " - URL failed: Blocked by robots.txt (" + urls[i] + ")");
                    continue;
                }
                if (returnInfo.links.contains(urls[i])) {
                    System.out.println("Iter " + info.iteration + " - URL failed: Exact link already passed (" + urls[i] + ")");
                    continue;
                }
                if (returnInfo.domains.contains(getDomain(urls[i]))) {
                    System.out.println("Iter " + info.iteration + " - URL failed: Domain already passed (" + getDomain(urls[i]) + ") (" + urls[i] + ")");
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("Iter " + info.iteration + " - URL valid: Distict domain (" + getDomain(urls[i]) + ") (" + urls[i] + ")");
                returnInfo.links.add(urls[i]);
                returnInfo.domains.add(getDomain(urls[i]));
                returnInfo.iteration = info.iteration + 1;
                returnInfo.scanLink = urls[i];

                returnInfo = getSixStepsRecursive(returnInfo);
                if (returnInfo.success) {
                    return returnInfo;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return returnInfo;

    }

    private static boolean canGetRobotsTxt(String url) {
        try {
            URI cur = new URI(url);
            if (!robotstxts.containsKey(cur.getHost())) {
                String rtxt = downloadString("http://" + cur.getHost() + "/robots.txt");
                String[] lines = rtxt.split("\n");
                ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String line : lines) {
                    if (line.endsWith("\r"))
                        line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                    if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("disallow: ")) {
                        line = line.substring(10);
                        ar.add(line);
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("allow: ")) {
                        line = line.substring(7);
                        ar.remove(line);
                    }
                }
                robotstxts.put(cur.getHost(), ar);
            }
            ArrayList<String> a = robotstxts.get(cur.getHost());
            for (String s : a) {
                String[] sw = s.split("\\Q*\\E");
                String s2 = "^i";
                for (String s3 : sw) {
                    s2 += "\\Q" + s3 + "\\E(.+)";
                }
                s2 = s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 4);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s2);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(cur.getPath());
                if (m.find()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static HashMap<String, String> getEntitiesFromEnt(String url) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> e = new HashMap<>();
        String ent = downloadString(url);
        while (ent.contains("  ")) ent = ent.replace("  ", " ");
        String[] lines = ent.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.startsWith("<!ENTITY")) {
                String[] f = line.split(" ");
                e.put("&" + f[1] + ";", f[3].substring(1, f[3].length() - 1));
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    private static String downloadString(String url) throws Exception {
        URL cur = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = cur.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "URLConnection/1.7 (Any system) VardenCG/3.0");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String content = "", line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) content += line + "\n";
        in.close();
        return content;
    }

    private static String stripHTMLEntities(String html) {
        for (Entry<String, String> e : entities.entrySet())
            html = html.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        Pattern ep = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);");
        Matcher m = ep.matcher(html);
        while (m.find()) {
            if (!m.group(1).equals("38"))
                html = html.replace("&#" + m.group(1) + ";", String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
        }
        Pattern ep1 = Pattern.compile("&(x|X)([\\da-fA-F]+);");
        Matcher m2 = ep1.matcher(html);
        while (m2.find()) {
            if (!m.group(1).equals("26")) {
                html = html.replace("&x" + m2.group(2) + ";", String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2), 16)));
                html = html.replace("&X" + m2.group(2) + ";", String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2), 16)));
            }
        }
        html = html.replace("&#38;", "\0").replace("&x26;", "\0").replace("&X26;", "\0").replace("\0", "&");
        return html;
    }

    private static String getDomain(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        String host = uri.getHost().toLowerCase();
        String[] subDomainTree = host.split("\\.");
        String[] commonSLs = {"ac", "co", "com", "gov", "ltd", "me", "net", "org"};
        boolean isCommonSL = false;
        try {
            String secondLevel = subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 2];
            for (String sl : commonSLs) {
                if (sl.equals(secondLevel)) {
                    isCommonSL = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            return host;
        }
        try {
            if (isCommonSL) {
                return subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 3] + "." +
                        subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 2] + "." + 
                        subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 1];
            } else {
                return subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 2] + "." + 
                        subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 1];
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            return subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 2] + "." + 
                    subDomainTree[subDomainTree.length - 1];
        }
    }

    private static class IterationInfo {
        public ArrayList<String> domains = new ArrayList<>();
        public ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
        public String scanLink = "";
        public int iteration = 1;
        public boolean success = false;
    }

}
```

Parameter used: `http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/`

Output: http://pastebin.no/34cd (Had to post on other site because it was too big for codegolf)

There's a lot of stuff going on here.

First of all, I have to parse HTML entities like &em; &39; and &x2F;. The named entities have to be translated, I do that by downloading the definitions from W3C.

I also need to figure out the host of the URL, taking into account common second level domains like co, edu etc. (.co.uk, .edu.uk, ...)

Then I need to parse robots.txt.

I don't have time to write more now, but oh well, there's my contribution.

-- bilde2910

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this challenge your code and output certainly seem valid. Well done! I'm always pleased to see someone take some time on a challenge i set. Thanks :)

Comment: @BenPaton Thank you! Just trying my best to help out. It's not perfect, but it works to a certain degree. For some reason my 700 lines of "URL failed: Banned by robots.txt" didn't make it in. Oh well.